# Is it possible to filter the integer with decimal points using filter_var in PHP?

Tags: php

I need to filter the value like this `100.50` using filter_var in PHP.
Now I am using like this
`filter_var($_POST['amount'],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) : '';`
And it gives  me the result is `10050` .
How can I solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your expected result then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An integer does not have decimal fractions, so the validation must fail (although I find the sanitation result of `100.50` turning into `10050` pretty bizarre on PHP's end. WTF?).

You would need to use a different filter, e.g. `FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT`.

[List of PHP validate filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

Comment: That's because he's using the sanitation filter, not the validation filter. The docs say about the sanitation one: "remove all characters except digits, plus and minus sign."

Answer (score 3):

The number 100.50 is *not* an integer, it is a float.  To filter variables that are floats you should use `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT`.  This will remove all unwanted characters and leave you with a float.

Here is some example code:

```
$_POST['amount'] = 100.50;
// Use FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION to allow decimal places to remain without being removed
$amount = filter_var($_POST['amount'],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);

print $amount;
// When you print it will print out 100.50
```

Remember this only works if your installed PHP is version 5.2.0 or better.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want to use filter_var because you want to remove all other characters, use FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT and then cast to integer.

Answer (score 0):

`intval` returns the integer part of your variable (everything without the decimal places).

`intval(100.50)` would return `100`. However, I'm not sure if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One should take care when converting decimal stings to floating values. Doing so can result in rounding errors. If you must keep the decimal precision, using preg_replace to remove all characters except for numbers and the period would be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

We need to pass flag in the third parameter of filter_var function as -

```
print filter_var($_POST['amount'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
```

Cheers