# PHP -How to extract prices with comma from text

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to extract numbers from a text while keeping the comma
For example I have this text "87,45 €" so I would like to extract only 87,4 and change it to a number to perform calculations
Example 2 "+ 4,99 € Tax" I would like to extract 4,99 .

I found this solution but it is removing the comma , it will output 8745

```
$int = (int) filter_var($productPrice, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Is there a way to convert to a number and keep the comma , because those are prices?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to filter the integer with decimal points using filter\_var in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537458/is-it-possible-to-filter-the-integer-with-decimal-points-using-filter-var-in-php)

Comment: Note that you can't store 4,99 to int, use float instead https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php

Comment: I tried with   $amount = ,filter_var($productPrice,FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION); nut I still get 8745 isntead of 87,45

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325363/converting-a-number-with-comma-as-decimal-point-to-float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
echo preg_replace('([^\d,.]+)', '', '4,99 € Tax');
```

Result

```
4,99
```

This will replace anything that isnt a digit `\d` or period `.`

Comment: thank you so much it worked                                                                                                           
          $price =preg_replace('([^\d,.]+)', '', $productPrice);
        echo "<script>console.log('Debug Objects: " . $price. "' );</script>";